# How to create a dataset from a sequence of random characters to segment them

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset

I've a sequence of random letters like this:

'xrrlzxmnbbazpcljsvtnpjizbnangxasvyljsvtntpjizbbjangpilaenztli*yacnhkhlpfnpfstljsvtentpsbtaythecqhssagtobpbazpcweyacnpilaenztlsixwukmukhplfhkhphlf...'

This sequence actually is composed by sequences of words (for example xrrlzxmn,bbazpc,ljsvtnpjiz and so on..) that sometimes they repeat themselves but with a little change (xrrl**k**zxm, xrrl**xz**mn or a delete of one char for example). I would want to create a dataset to apply clustering techniques, but I have no idea how to do it...
I don't know how to represent a word like "xrrlzxmn" in terms of numbers or vector... which attributes (columns of dataset) could be right?

My **goal** is to segment that sequence in something like this:
*'xrrlzxmn bbazpc ljsvtnpjiz bnangx asvyljsvtnt pjizbbjangpil aenzt li*yacnhk hlpfnpfs tljsvte ntps btaythecq hssagto bpbazp cweyacnpi laenztlsi xwukmuk hplfhk hphlf...'*

I have to insert a separator between the words, but since I have not a dictionary, I'm in a unsupervisionated scenario, so I am thinking to work with clusters

Comment: What's a "dataset"? There's nothing formal matching that term in Python.

Comment: Do your words have a constant character length or other factor to help segment them, such as starting or ending in a specific sequence?

Comment: Or, if I'm understanding correctly, you want to use ML to scan for a repetitive pattern and then use that to separate out the original mega-string?

Comment: No, my words don't have a constant character length because their length can change, for example an possible words can be "hplfhk", but in the mega-string you can find this word in various forms:
- hplfh (delete the ''k'' letter for example, but could be also another letter)
- hpalfhk (add the "a" at third position, but could be whatever position)
- hplfhk (the word could be the same)
- hplhfk (a swap between 2 letter could happen)
- hplh*k (a letter could be transform in another letter)

About the third comment, yes, you understood well

Comment: Hey, I did a bit of digging and found the following two links you might be interested in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups and 
https://dzone.com/articles/the-levenshtein-algorithm-1#targetText=The%20Levenshtein%20distance%20is%20a,one%20word%20into%20the%20other.

The trick here is that you may have to employ a rolling 'window' over your initial string - as you don't know how evenly the string should be split, it may be worth running a loop from like 3 to 10 characters and seeing how many clusters there are.

Comment: Heey, thank you very much! I will read those link and I will try that!